# Creating new matrix out of one column by order of two other columns

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

So I have a matrix A, take as an example

```
       4   6   3.5
       3   6   -1
A  =   5   2   0.7
       4   3   1.2
```

I now want to use Matlab to make a matrix B out of the last column of A in a very specific way. The rows of B should be ordered by the first column of A (in ascending order) and the columns of B should be ordered (ascending) by the second column of A. This can give empty elements in B, which should be assigned NaN. Applied to the example above this gives

```
        NaN   NaN   -1
B  =    NaN   1.2   3.5
        0.7   NaN   NaN
```

Note that the number of rows and columns in B depend on the number of unique elements in the first and second column of A respectively.

I have tried a few different things trying to be clever with Matlab indexing but so far no success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
[~,J1,K1] = unique(A(:,1));
[~,J2,K2] = unique(A(:,2));
sz = [numel(J1) numel(J2)];
B = nan(sz);
B(sub2ind(sz, K1, K2)) = A(:,3);
```

first use `unique` to gather the unique items and their indices in the original column. The size of `B` is determined by number of unique elements in first and second column of `A`.
Now use linear indexing (obtained using `sub2ind`) to put the values in third column in the right place.